# How to immediately invoke a C++ lambda?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, c++14

A constructor from a class I'm inheriting requires a non-trivial object to be passed in.  Similar to this:

```
MyFoo::MyFoo() : SomeBase( complexstuff )
{
    return;
}
```

The `complexstuff` has little to do with `MyFoo`, so I didn't want to have to pass it in.

Instead of writing some kind of 1-off temporary function that returns `complexstuff` I used a lambda.  What took me a few minutes to figure out is I have to *invoke* the lambda.  So my code now looks like this:

```
MyFoo::MyFoo() : SomeBase(
    []()
    {
        /* blah blah do stuff with complexstuff */
        return complexstuff;
    } () )
{
    return;
}
```

If you didn't catch it, it is subtle.  But after the lambda body, I had to put `()` to tell the compiler to immediately "run" the lambda.  Which made sense after I figured out what I had done wrong.  Otherwise, without the `()` to invoke the lambda, gcc says something similar to this:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'SomeBase(<lambda()>)'
```

But now that has me thinking -- did I do this correctly?  Is there a better way in C++11 or C++14 to tell the compiler that I want it to immediately invoke a lambda I've written?  Or is appending an empty `()` like I did the usual way to do this?

Comment: Why write a lambda and immediately invoke it? It doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @n.m.: because the complexstuff needs some statements to be computed (such as some `for` loop)

Comment: @n.m.: Why not? This is basically the standard way to achieve what GCC's *expression statements* extension is offering (`({ ... })`). I.e. when you need an expression that involves more than just operators.

Comment: So this is for embedding statements in an expression. Did I understand it correctly ?

Comment: As a matter of coding style, the *// complexstuff //* should be in a private static member function of the same class (MyFoo). In other words, **"1-off temporary function"** would have been the correct approach. You would have been "corrected" if your code were reviewed by other people. There is no reason to use lambda in this case. I leave this comment because apparently someone's answer (not mine) got downvoted (not me) for not pointing out this obvious issue. The question is legitimate but the code sample might have seemed superfluous to some StackOverflow users.

Comment: I shared some related ideas here: [What is a lambda expression in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15153194/86967)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> But now that has me thinking -- did I do this correctly?

Yes you did.

> Is there a better way in C++11 or C++14 to tell the compiler that I want it to immediately invoke a lambda I've written?

Not that I know of. A lambda is also just a function object, so you *need* to have a `()` to call it, there is no way around it (except of course some function that invokes the lambda like `std::invoke`).

If you want you can drop the `()` after the capture list, because your lambda doesn't take any parameters.

> Or is appending an empty `()` like I did the usual way to do this?

Yes, it is the shortest way. As said before, `std::invoke` would also work instead, but it requires more typing. I would say a direct call with `()` is the usual way it is done.

Comment: Just to illustrate the middle point, `[](){}` is an empty lambda function object, and `[]{}()` is a `void` expression resulting from evaluating an empty lambda.

Answer (score 9):

In C++17 you can use [`std::invoke`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke).  This does the exact same thing as you did, but perhaps you will find this clearer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

void foo(int i)
{
  std::cout << i << '\n';
}

int main()
{
  foo( std::invoke( []() { return 1; } ) );
}
```

Comment: This is 100% pointless. `std::invoke` is for generic code where you might be given a function object, PMF, function pointer, etc. When you already know _how_ to invoke your callable, `std::invoke` serves no purpose other than to slow build times.

Comment: @ildjarn Thank you for repeating what I said in the answer and downvoting.

Comment: It doesn't "do the exact same thing", it does a lot _more_, hence the increased build times. You didn't mention _that_. ;-] This is an abuse of `std::invoke` more than a use of it; even if it's subjectively "clearer" in some context, it's objectively worse regardless when you have a fixed form of callable.

Comment: @ildjarn `std::invoke` is used here to stress out the function invocation and not rely  the `()`-detail which can be missed by the person reading the code. This alone can save developer's time. The technique is explained in this book: https://www.bfilipek.com/2016/11/iife-for-complex-initialization.html#improving-readability-of-iife

Answer (score 8):

There's no way to tell the compiler to invoke the lambda immediately. The simplest course (both in terms of complexity and number of typed characters) is what you did already. It's also very idiomatic for anyone who has worked with languages that have closures (I'm thinking JavaScript here).

If you want to avoid the syntax, then either modify `SomeBase` or `complexstuff` to execute the callable.

---

If all you want is syntactic sugar for invoking the lambda, you can always do what something like Alexandrescu's SCOPE_GUARD does, and abuse operator overloading:

<kbd>[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/df29e1d2f29dfd9c)</kbd>

```
#include <iostream>

namespace detail {

enum class invoke_t{};

template<class Callable>
auto operator+(invoke_t, Callable c) -> decltype(c()) {
    return c();
}

}

constexpr detail::invoke_t invoke{};


int main() {
    invoke + []() {
        std::cout << "called";
    };
}
```

But I wouldn't. Inventing your own DSL will just make your code worse to maintain. Stick to the idioms that utilize plain language constructs.

Comment: That `operator+` is funny :P Never seen something like this. Can't you use `decltype(auto)` for the return type instead of the trailing return type? Aren't they the same?

Comment: Inventing your own DSL will make your code worse to maintain for most purposes. But for some rare cases, it can make the code easier to maintain. For example, something like `fn("myFunctionName")(1, "hi", cast("void *")(variable("var")))` is a lot more readable than `Function{ "myFunctionName", { FunctionArgument{ std::to_string(1) }, FunctionArgument{ "hi" }, FunctionArgument{ Cast{ "void *", Variable{ "var" } } } } }` (especially if it gets more complex). It just requires that the maintainer understands the dsl though

Comment: @Rakete1111 - The OP tagged C++11, I just stuck to that realm. You can use return type deduction, of course.

Comment: @StoryTeller Well, in the question OP mentioned C++14 too, so I just added that tag to the question... :)

Comment: @Justin - That's a lot of ifs :) I agree that a DSL isn't inherently a bad thing (SCOPE_GUARD, overloading operator| for ranges and so forth come to mind), but it's very much a judgement call.

Comment: I guess, `invoke` should be declared `inline` to allow definitions in multiple translation units: `inline constexpr enum {} invoke{};`

Comment: @DietmarKühl - I was relying on the implied internal linkage of const namespace scoped objects. But now I see that probably made the template a big odr violation on account of the annonymous type of the object in every TU. It should be fixed now, and be valid C++11 (my original intent).

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a better way

You could also consider having a private static member function building the `complexstuff`, something like

```
class MyFoo : public Base {
private:
    static SomeComplexType compute_complex_stuff() {
      SomeComplexType complexstuff;
      /*compute the complexstuff */
      return complexstuff;
    };
public: 
    MyFoo() : Base(compute_complex_stuff()) {};
};
```

I don't know if it is better than defining a lambda expression and applying it immediately; that is IMHO a matter of taste; for a *short* lambda body I would prefer a lambda expression immediately applied (but perhaps some compiler would create the temporary closure in that case, so it might be slower without optimizations; I expect most C++11 compilers to be able to make that optimization).

BTW, GCC provides the [statement expression](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html) language extension (also understood by Clang) for your purposes. With it you could write

```
MyFoo::MyFoo : Base (({
  SomeComplexType complexstuff;
  /*compute the complexstuff */
  return complexstuff;
}) {};
```