# Can I call a lambda without first assigning it to a variable?

Tags: c++11, lambda

I'm learning how to use lambda functions. Why doesn't my last lambda run automatically if not assigned to a variable? All the previous ones work as expected.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    std::thread t([]() {
        std::cout << "thread function\n";
    });
    std::cout << "main thread\n";
    t.join();

    auto a = []() -> int {
        return 1 + 2;
    };
    int n = a();
    cout << n << endl;

    auto b = []() -> void {
        cout << "sup" << endl;
    };
    b();

    //why doesn't this run automatically?
    []() -> void {
        cout << "hellur!" << endl;
    };

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because you don't call it.

Comment: Can I call a lambda without first assigning it to a variable?

Comment: Yes, use function call operator `()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to immediately invoke a C++ lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44868369/how-to-immediately-invoke-a-c-lambda)

Comment: ... why would you want to do this out of curiosity? Why not simply include the actual code there instead of a lambda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
[]() -> void {
    cout << "hellur!" << endl;
}();
```