# Declaring lambda with int type not working

Tags: c++, function, c++11, lambda, function-call

I wanted to use the lambda function somehow, but it doesn't work, and I don't know why.

```
vector<int> v;

/* ... */

int median = [](vector<int> a)
{
    sort(a.begin(), a.end());
    return a[a.size() / 2];
}
```

I created a lambda function, but how can I call it?
`int median = [](vector<int> a) { ... } (v)`? But it doesn't work too.

I have seen lambda functions only in some examples like making custom comparator. Can I make it work in my case somehow?

Comment: The lambda function is not `int` type... You can use  `auto median = ` or call it in the place `}(v);`

Comment: why is it not `int` type? I'm returning an element of array, so it is supposed to be `int`?

Comment: You are returning lambda function as it's not called in place.

Comment: @RussianStranger a lambda is a _callable object_.  An `int` is something entirely different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can I make it work in my case somehow?

Yes you can. You can either call it  [immediately after the definition](https://godbolt.org/z/fbod7vE7h):

```
int median = [](std::vector<int> a) {
    std::sort(a.begin(), a.end());
    return a[a.size() / 2];   
}(v); 
//^^  --> invoke immediately with argument
```

See for reference: [How to immediately invoke a C++ lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44868369/how-to-immediately-invoke-a-c-lambda)

or define the lambda and call it later.

```
/* const */ auto median = [](std::vector<int> a) { ...}
int res = median(v);
```

Note that I have used `auto` type, to specify the type of the lambda function. This is because, lambda has so-called **closure type**, which we can only mention either by a `auto` or any *type erasure mechanism* such as `std::function`.

From [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)

> The lambda expression is a prvalue expression of **unique unnamed non-union non-aggregate class type, known as closure type**, which is declared (for the purposes of ADL) in the smallest block scope, class scope, or namespace scope that contains the lambda expression.

Comment: One more case may be "capture-less lambdas" can be stored in typed function pointers as well. I hope that would be too deep into the question (IMO).

Answer (score 1):

'median' is a function but you can declare the return type like  so.

```
#include<functional>
vector<int> v;

/* ... */

std::function<int(vector<int>)> median = [](vector<int> a)->int
{
    sort(a.begin(), a.end());
    return a[a.size() / 2];
};
```

Comment: `auto` would be a much better way to declare the lambda.

Comment: Agreed. Mine is just for clarity.